# Is it necessary to use Process.WaitForExit after Process.Kill?

Tags: .net, process, kill-process

Is it necessary to use Process.WaitForExit after Process.Kill?
What if the calling process exits right after it calls Process.Kill?
Would this cause Process.Kill to fail?

**Edit:** I need to kill a process on exiting my application. At this point I do not intend to handle the situations when kill fails so it is not necessary for me to wait for the process to exit. So if calling WaitForExit is not necessary I could just skip it.

Comment: What problem are you seeing and what code do you currently have?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to the [documentation on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.kill.aspx) (emphasis mine)

> Note The Kill method **executes asynchronously**. After calling the Kill
>   method, call the WaitForExit method **to wait for the process to exit**,
>   or check the HasExited property **to determine if the process has
>   exited**.

If you don't need to wait, of if you don't need to determine if the process actually exists, then I suppose you don't need to call `WaitForExit` or check `HasExited`.